# Can't perform Factory Reset on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 is a little laggy and I just want to do a Factory reset. I can't. Everytime I try it I end up with this error:

[image]

I even tried using tool from Microsoft (installer).

I get this error:

[image]

I want to reinstall my Windows 10 while preserving my files. I don't have enough space to back up them all, so I just want Factory reset. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Due to your current system state, using the Reset feature within Windows 10 will not be possible, but you can still achieve your goal.

1. Open the Settings application
2. Click Update & Security
3. Click Recovery
4. Click the [*Learn how to start fresh with a clean installation of Windows*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh) link under **More recovery options**.

[image]

6. Download [RefreshWindowsTool.exe](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=817236)

[image]
 7. Execute the tool
 8. Follow the on-screen prompts

At this point you will asked if you want to keep your personal files, you should choose this option, instead of the **keep nothing** option.  After you do that the tool will download what is required and reinstall Windows and your personal files will be kept.

Comment: Amazing, that was that kind of answer I was looking for. I hope this will work. Thank you! I will let you know.

Comment: Situation is the same. Installation program didn't inicialize properly, try to restart PC. When I restart, it's the same.

Comment: I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DtEmASak4g

It looks promising, but I don't have install.wim in my Windows 10 ISO, I have install.esd instead.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I am desparate.

Comment: If you are saying my answer does not work, I need more to work with, other than "nothing works".

Answer (score 0):

partition your hardrive or ssd drive into 2 parts, install a new version of windows 10 on the new partition. Make sure to not delete your old partition. Make sure you dont make the partitions equal in space, so you wont forget which partition is the one your trying to fix.

Afterwards, boot into the new version and go to "your drive letter should be c: but could be different" and copy C:\Windows to the original partition where your First OS is at and replace everything. This will fix your windows part there.

Now after that, restart your pc, while tapping F12, choose your old partition. Boot into it, and now you can do a repair install. After the repair install, delete the old partition.

Comment: "I don't have enough space to back up" stops this working ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Some people think that needed space for backup is the whole drive letter. This still might work.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://youtu.be/mw_EuTYAGLI

Comment: @user433966 that looks promising, try it, let me know if it works. worst case scenario you just delete that new partition and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a little bit too complicated, I'd rather fix the default Factory reset opiton if there is someone who knows how to do it. I will wait and if there won't be another answer, I will try your method. Thank you very much again :)

Comment: @user433966 You won't be able to fix it.  The image that handles it is corrupt.  The solution is Refresh, this downloads the same image, and uses that instead.