# Reversibly Reinstall Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, license

I have some little problems with Windows 10.  I have modified system files over the past few years, so would just like to do a "reversible reinstall experiment" to see if the problems go away.

So, one way to go about this is to clone and replace the HDD, and then do a [Fresh Start](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012986) which should bring me to the newest Windows 10 in one step.

Will I have a Windows licensing problem when I then replace the HDD back and forth to compare performance?  The license is just a basic OEM license for Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I have a Windows licensing problem when I then replace the HDD back and forth to compare performance?

You absolutely will not have an activation problem based on the exact details you have described.  **The activation of Windows is not affected by the storage device.**

Since you will be running it on the same hardware, the activation status of your installation, will not actually change.

> So, one way to go about this is to clone and replace the HDD, and then do a Fresh Start which should bring me to the newest Windows 10 in one step.

You would be better of doing a Reset and choosing to ["keep nothing"](https://superuser.com/questions/1172427/cant-perform-factory-reset-on-windows-10/1172457#1172457) due to the nature of how it works.  Fresh Start requires you to download the image, while the image used by Reset, already exists and on your system.

Comment: Fresh Start requires you to download the image whole Reset already exists and on your system.

Comment: @bobuhito - Commentary is designed to be temporary.  I have been flagging any commentary, as "no longer needed", that wasn't specific feedback on how to approve my answer to this question.

Comment: My understanding is that Reset will use the files in "/Windows/WinSxS" to replace the system files, but WinSxS apparently keeps previous versions too. Without further clarification, I assume Windows has intentionally made it so that a reinstall with Reset vs Fresh Start leads to different (probably subtle) computer operation, I understand your point that Reset is faster and requires no internet, but can't yet accept this answer because my goal was to get as close to the install Windows wants and have the fewest remnants of my old OS.

Comment: @bobuhito - Your understanding isn't one hundred percent accurate.  In any event, they have combined Reset and Fresh Start, with the release of Windows 10 version 2004.