# Windows reset vs formatting?

Tags: windows, formatting, virus-removal

I stupidly downloaded some ROMs and exacuted a .exe, so it looks like I'm going to have to format/reset my pc. Is windows reset not as good as formatting the drive? It looks like windows reset will reuse the key I already have activated, but I don't know if formatting it will make me have to get a new key or not.

Comment: What make/model PC?  Most brand name PCs have a Windows key imbedded in the firmware, and the OS will automatically detect it on reinstall.   If you can still run software, you may be able to download something like Magic Jelly Bean Key finder to find your Windows key if its not imbedded and not attached to your PC.

Comment: @davidgo - All OEM hardware is required to store the license in the ACPI table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversibly Reinstall Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1560210/reversibly-reinstall-windows-10).  My answer applies to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has been compromised by a virus, resetting Windows *might* get rid of it, but you can’t be 100% sure. You should never trust a machine that has been compromised unless it has been fully wiped.

You needn’t worry about the activation. If this is an OEM PC, Windows will activate automatically without you even needing to enter a key. If this is an aftermarket rig with your own copy of Windows, you can activate the same key on it as many times as you need to.